# Get rid of useless scroll bars on fancybox iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, fancybox

I have some content I want to show in iframe with fancybox. When I use it, it pops up with horizontal and vertical scroll bars even though all the content is inside of it. Inspecting it in Firefox shows that when I click on `html` everything is inside but there is a little left over that is outside of the highlighted box. The next level up is `iframe.fancybox-iframe` which includes the scroll bars. I looked at the css and that has padding and margins set to zero so I don't know why the scroll bars are there. Right now as far as options I just have `autoSize:false`. All I have inside the body of the page I want to show is a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the css:

```
.style{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

If it didn't help, please post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: I actually found what was causing it. Something inside the form had padding that was interfering, but adding your solution to the html tag works as well. I will accept answer when it allows me to.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone wonders which class name to use

```
.fancybox-inner {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

And if you found a small white background you can reset it using

```
.fancybox-skin {
    background: inherit;
}
```